# how to have two nodes on localhost server elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on localhost, and in order to understand what cluster is and what a node is, i want to have two nodes on my localhost.

just to make it clear:
when I lunch the elasticsearch from bin/elasticsear, i'm luching a cluster, right?

if yes, then where is the node?

and how can I have two nodes on my cluster?

#### update

You may ask why do I need that?

It is because, as you may know, each index in an elasticsearch cluster has shads. default is 5 shards for one index, and default is each index has 1 replica, so each index be default has 10 shards, 5 for original data, and 5 for replica. in elasticsearch, **it is impossible** to put the replica's shards and the original shards on the same node. thus, in my case, i have one cluster running 5 original shards for each index, but i don't have the 5 replica's shads. that's why my index status is yellow (not green, not red), i want it to be green, thus i need another node in my cluster to put the shards, but i just have one elasticsearch server (localhost), that's why i need another node on my localhost elasticsearch server

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start elasticsearch server a `master node` gets up by default.In order to run another node, just go to another terminal and start your elastic-search server again.
Make sure that:

- `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true` in `elasticsearch.yml`.

Since elasticsearch is `distributed` in nature, the newly added instance will be automatically detected by the already existing node(s).You can verify this from the terminal.

Suppose the name of existing node was `node1` and newly added node is `node2`.

- On the terminal where `node1` was running you will see this message:

  `[node1] added [node2]`
- On the terminal where `node2` has been started you will see message:

  `[node2] detected_master [node1]`

Both the nodes detected each other automatically. You can run following query in sense to check the nodes running:

```
GET /_cluster/state
```

This will list all the nodes